# iOS9 supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow stops getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to show 1 or 2 UIViewcontrollers in Landscape mode while others in Portrait.
For this purpose I have implemented this function in AppDelegate.

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return self.orientation;
}
```

where in AppDelegate.h, orientation is:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIInterfaceOrientationMask orientation;
```

In UIViewcontroller(s) where I need Landscape orientation. I place this code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.appDelegate.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.appDelegate.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

However, when I go to 'LandscapeViewController' it works ok, I go back, it works ok, I again go to 'LandscapeViewController' its ok, and then when I comes back, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method stop getting called. Any reason for that? or I am doing something weird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using UITabBarController  create a custom class for UITabBarController and place this code there

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and place this in your view controllers according to your need.

place this code in appDelegate

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

    id rootViewController = [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:window.rootViewController];

    if (rootViewController != nil)
    {
        if ([rootViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(canRotate)])
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        }
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIViewController*) topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(id)rootViewController
{

    if (rootViewController == nil)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController  class]])
    {
        UITabBarController *selectedTabBarController = rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:selectedTabBarController.selectedViewController];
    }
    else if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        UINavigationController *selectedNavController = rootViewController;
        return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:selectedNavController.visibleViewController];
    }
    else
    {
        UIViewController *selectedViewController = rootViewController;
        if (selectedViewController.presentedViewController != nil)
        {
            return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:selectedViewController.presentedViewController];
        }
    }
    return rootViewController;
}
```

and place this in your view controller

```
-(void)canRotate
{

}
```